# How can I go through the columns of a matrix in matlab and add them each to a specific column of a sum matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, sum, vectorization

Supose there is a Matrix

```
A =

 1     3     2    4
 4     2     5    8
 6     1     4    9
```

and I have a Vector containing the "class" of each column of this matrix for example

```
v = [1 , 1 , 2 , 3]
```

How can I sum the columns of the matrix to a new matrix as column vectors each to the column of their class? In this example columns 1 and 2 of A would added to the first column of the new matrix, column 2 to the 3 to the 2nd, column 4 the the 3rd.

Like

```
SUM =

4    2    4
6    5    8
7    4    9
```

Is this possible without loops?

Comment: Don't fear the MATLAB loop! It is quite fast nowadays and often easy to read!

Comment: @knedlsepp ... but removes most of the fun :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo: Well, I'm as much into a good vectorized solution as the next guy, but if the `for`-loop beats all the other approaches, why avoid it? ;-)

Comment: so @user3563898 does any of the answer below helped you? Please mark one of them as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One of the perfect scenarios to combine the powers of `accumarray` and `bsxfun` -

```
%// Since we are to accumulate columns, first step would be to transpose A
At = A.'  %//'

%// Create a vector of linear IDs for use with ACCUMARRAY later on
idx = bsxfun(@plus,v(:),[0:size(A,1)-1]*max(v))

%// Use ACCUMARRAY to accumulate rows from At, i.e. columns from A based on the IDs
out = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),At(:)),[],size(A,1)).'
```

---

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     3     2     4     6     0
     4     2     5     8     9     2
     6     1     4     9     8     9
v =
     1     1     2     3     3     2
out =
     4     2    10
     6     7    17
     7    13    17
```

Comment: Nice.  I was trying to figure out how to do it with `accumarray`. +1.

Comment: @Benoit_11 No solution is perfect without `bsxfun`! ;)

Comment: `bsxfun`,  `accumarray` and _non-conjugate_ transpose: delightful answer!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `accumarray` in 2D. Generate a grid with the vector `v` and then apply `accumarray`:

```
A = A.';

v = [1 1 2 3]; 

[X, Y] = ndgrid(v,1:size(A,2));
```

Here `X` and `Y` look like this:

```
X =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3


Y =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

Then apply `accumarray`:

```
B=accumarray([X(:) Y(:)],A(:)),

SUM = B.'

SUM =

     4     2     4
     6     5     8
     7     4     9
```

As you see, using `[X(:) Y(:)]` create the following array:

```
ans =

     1     1
     1     1
     2     1
     3     1
     1     2
     1     2
     2     2
     3     2
     1     3
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
```

in which the vector `v` containing the "class" is replicated 3 times since there are 3 unique classes that are to be summed up together.

EDIT:

As pointed out by knedlsepp you can get rid of the transpose to `A` and `B` like so:

```
[X2, Y2] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),v);

B = accumarray([X2(:) Y2(:)],A(:))
```

which ends up doing the same. I find it a bit more easier to visualize with the transposes but that gives the same result.

Comment: Nice.  This makes more sense to me.

Comment: Why the transposes? Couldn't you just use: `[X, Y] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),v);`?

Comment: Yep indeed; I found it easier to visualize with `A` transposed but you're absolutely right @knedlsepp.

Comment: How I wish Mathworks extended `accumarray` to work with a matrix as second argument...

Comment: @LuisMendo - I wish that too.  It would make a lot of the algorithms I develop easier to code.

Answer (score 2):

How about a one-liner?

```
result = full(sparse(repmat(v,size(A,1),1), repmat((1:size(A,1)).',1,size(A,2)), A));
```

Comment: `full(sparse(...` instead of `accumarray`? I take it you didn't want to post a solution that was too similar to *Benoit_11*'s. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Benoit_11 already covered the `accumarray` way :-) And using `sparse` has the advantage that the accumulation can be done directly with _columns_, not just with numbers as `accumarray` forces you to. But on second thought yes, it's pretty similar actually

Comment: @knedlsepp Perhaps I should delete it?

Comment: That was certainly not my intention!

Comment: @knedlsepp I wasn't sure about what you meant :-) My train of thought was "using `sparse` allows working with columns, which `accumarray` doesn't". But the resulting code is certainly almost the same

Comment: I just felt a disturbance in the force, that the #1 SO `accumarray`rista would go for `full(sparse` instead. Well, when R2015a finally is installed on most machines, you can go for a `repelem` instead of the `repmat` for a one-liner using `accumarray` without the ugly `reshape(,[],1)`. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Hahaha. Actually the #1 `accumarray`er is [chappjc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2778484/chappjc)! Pity that he's not very active in Matlab lately

Comment: Not according to [my calculations](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273107/which-matlab-users-have-the-most-answers-containing-a-certain-function)!

Comment: @knedlsepp :-D Alright, alright. Now, the truly amazing thing is that _more than one third_ of Divakar's answers contain `bsxfun`! Oh I think we already talked about this before, didn't we?

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimize prematurely!

The `for` loop performs fine for your problem:

```
out = zeros(size(A,1), max(v));
for i = 1:numel(v)
    out(:,v(i)) = out(:,v(i)) + A(:,i);
end
```

BTW: With *fine*, I mean: fast, fast, fast!